# PostgreSQL div function not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having troubles with my query in PostgreSQL.

I'm trying to divide the results of two queries without success.

```
with s1 as (
    select count(*)
    from university.sevent as p3
    where p3.edate not in (
        select p1.edate
        from university.sevent as p1
            join university.semester as p2
                on p1.edate between p2.sdate and p2.edate
    )
),
s2 as (
    select count(p1.edate)
    from university.sevent as p1
        join university.semester as p2
            on p1.edate between p2.sdate and p2.edate
)
select div(s1,s2);
```

but all I'm getting that it does not recognize `s1` or `s2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s1` and `s2` are the names of the tables, but you need the column names:

```
div(s1.count, s2.count) FROM s1 CROSS JOIN s2
```

but then I don't think you need the `div` function, since both fields are `bigint`. You could just use `s1.count / s2.count`.

Answer (score 0):

WITH query provides a way to write auxiliary statements for use in a larger query. It helps in breaking down complicated and large queries into simpler forms, which are easily readable. These statements often referred to as Common Table as a result s1 and s2 two diff table

```
with s1 as (
    select count(*) as C1
    from university.sevent as p3
    where p3.edate not in (
        select p1.edate
        from university.sevent as p1
            join university.semester as p2
                on p1.edate between p2.sdate and p2.edate
    )
),
s2 as (
    select count(p1.edate) as C2
    from university.sevent as p1
        join university.semester as p2
            on p1.edate between p2.sdate and p2.edate
)
select C1/C2 from s1,s2;
```